# Skipping comparison arrays when they are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a case that has to compare some arrays together and find the common element between all of them. The following code is working fine as long as all the array are loaded. But what if one (or even 5 of arrays) of the array is/are still empty and not loaded?

In case of having only two arrays I could do something like

```
  if ((arr1.length > 0) && (arr2.length === 0)) {
     newArr =arr1;
  }
```

but it is going be a big conditional snippet to check all 6 arrays in this way! How can I fix this so the code runs comparison against arrays only when they are loaded and skip the array(s) when they are empty?

```js
let newArr = [];
function common(arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4,arr5,arr6) {
  newArr = arr1.filter(function(e) {
    return arr2.indexOf(e) > -1 && 
           arr3.indexOf(e) > -1 && 
           arr4.indexOf(e) > -1 && 
           arr4.indexOf(e) > -1 && 
           arr5.indexOf(e) > -1 && 
           arr6.indexOf(e) > -1;
  });
}
common( [1, 2, 6, 5, 9,8], 
 [1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 9,8], 
        [6, 5, 4, 5,8], 
        [8, 2, 1, 6, 4], 
        [8, 2, 1, 6, 4], 
        //[8]
        []
        );

$('div').text(newArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Returns Nothing Because 6th Array is Empty</p>
  <div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it very hard way. Below is a very simple way.You do it in following steps:

- Use Rest Parameters instead of `arr1,arr2,...`.
- Remove the empty arrays using `filter()`. Like `Array.filter(x => x.length)`
- Create a object which will contain `keys` as number. And value as their count.
- Use `forEach()` on array of arrays.
- Increment the count of the object by apply `forEach()` on each of array.
- At last filter those keys of object which have count greater than given object.

```js
function common(...arrays) {
  let obj = {};
  let temp =  arrays.filter(x => x.length);
  //the below line will check if all the arrays empty
  if(!temp.length) console.log("All empty")
  temp.forEach(arr => {
    arr.forEach(x => {
      obj[x] = obj[x] + 1 || 1
    })
    
  })
  //console.log(temp)
  //console.log(Object.keys(obj))
  return Object.keys(obj).filter(a => obj[a] === temp.length).map(x => +x || x);
}
let newArr = common( [1, 2, 6, 5, 9,8], 
 [1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 9,8], 
        [6, 5, 4, 5,8,1], 
        [8, 2, 1, 6, 4], 
        [8, 2, 1, 6, 4],
        //[8]
        
        );

console.log(newArr)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lots Maheer but can you also let me know where can I put a flag if all the arrays are empty?

Comment: @MonaCoder Couldn't understand what you mean by **put a flag**. But if you want  to check that all the arrays are empty so I edited to post with comment inside code.

Comment: Thanks but it is not consoling out! anything when arrays are empty

Comment: @MonaCoder do you mean all the arrays should be empty or at least one?. If you mean at least one then change `if(!temp.length)` to `if(temp.length !== arrays.length)`

Answer (score 1):

Since your code is written in ES6, there is a very ES6-way to go about your problem.

What you basically want is to check all items in the first array against *n* number of arrays provided in the function's parameters/arguments and only return the item that is present in **all** arrays.

```
// Use ...arrs to store all subsequent arrays in parameter
function common(arr1, ...arrs) {
  return arr1.map(item => {

   const nonEmptyArrs = arrs.filter(arr => arr.length);

    // Go through all OTHER arrays and see if your item is present in them
    const isItemFound = nonEmptyArrs.forEach(arr => {
      return arr.indexOf(item) > -1;
    });

    // Now filter the array to remove all `false` entries
    const itemFoundCount = isItemFound.filter(i => i).length;

    // Only return item if it is found in ALL arrays
    // i.e. itemFoundCount must match the number of arrays
    if (itemFoundCount === nonEmptyArrs.length) {
      return item;
    }
  })
  .filter(item => item);    // Remove undefined entries
}
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
function common(arr1, ...arrs) {
  return arr1.map(item => {
    const nonEmptyArrs = arrs.filter(arr => arr.length);
    
    const itemFoundCount = nonEmptyArrs
      .map(arr => arr.includes(item))
      .filter(i => i)
      .length;
    
    // Only return item if it is found in ALL arrays
    if (itemFoundCount === nonEmptyArrs.length) {
      return item;
    }
  }).filter(item => item);
}

const newArr = common([1, 2, 6, 5, 9, 8], [1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 9, 8], [6, 5, 4, 5, 8], [8, 2, 1, 6, 4], [8, 2, 1, 6, 4], []);

console.log(newArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```